# Updating model after focus is lost on input control

Tags: angularjs

In this code:

```
<input class="form-control" ng-model="actionText" />
```

AngularJS will update the model actionText as the user types stuff in. If this model is being used elsewhere, such as in a controller, it gets updated as each character is typed. I can think of situations where that could actually be a bad thing. Maybe you only want the model value AFTER the user has moved focus from the input to something else, such as when you need to validate the input when it has completed. I could use Javascript's blur function to setup a handler to determine when focus is lost but that seems to be against the way Angular is meant to be. Is there an AngularJS way of updating the model after the input has lost focus?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `ngModelOptions` directive for this. With `ngModelOptions` you can further refine how the `ngModel` directive works. To achieve what you asked for, you may use it like this:

```
<input class="form-control" ng-model="actionText" 
   ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur'}"/>
```

You can find further information and a working example in the angular documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Comment: Would this be the recommended way of handling validation? In other words, after you lose focus, you want to validate the input for some pattern (address, phone number, etc.).

Comment: I don't ever recall reading about this in the docs (pre 1.3) but do love the addition of this functionality to support how models are updated.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way might be just use `ng-blur` to fire off something you want to do.

http://plnkr.co/edit/rhcliQRzUOBKQ3xKFrde?p=preview

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.myDataBlurred = $scope.myData;

  $scope.blurred = function() {
     $scope.myDataBlurred = $scope.myData;
  }
});

 <input ng-model='myData' ng-blur='blurred()' />

    <div>
      This will update as you type: {{myData}}
    </div>
    <div>
      This will update after you blur:  {{myDataBlurred}}
    </div>
```

Comment: I do like the ng-model-options as posted by @Nikolas.  Depends on your use case and version of angular.