# How to use orderBy in AngularJS (1.2) to sort, without having incomplete entries jump around

Tags: angularjs, sorting, input, crud, angularjs-orderby

Okay so I'm doing some basic CRUD with AngularJS. Here's the view:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat=="person in persons | orderBy:lastName">
        <td>
            {{person.firstName}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{person.lastName}}
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input ng-model="person.firstName">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input ng-model="person.lastName">
        </td>
        <td>
            <button ng-click="save(person)">Save</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is that as you type a new user into the inputs, the position of that row jumps around to where it fits alphabetically. Obviously I want this to happen, but only when the user is done typing and hits "save."

Comment: Use a temporary variable for the new user, and only add it to the users list when "Save" is clicked.

Comment: Related other solution: [Updating the model only after loosing focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513027/updating-model-after-focus-is-lost-on-input-control)

Comment: Move the new user row into a separate tbody that isn't affected by the ng-repeat orderBy.

Comment: @ryanyuyu, unfortunately that solution requires AngularJS 1.3+ and we're on 1.2 for IE8 support.

Comment: @CaptainStack ah that's too bad.  You might consider editing that information into the question so others don't try to use the `ng-model-options`.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722577/how-to-let-ng-model-not-update-immediately) I think has an answer for 1.2.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Couldn't get that to work. A couple comments said it doesn't. Other answer is also for 1.3. I maybe have to just do something a little hackier to make this work.

Comment: @CaptainStack man that is really too bad.  I do suggest upvoting one of the relevant comments and/or downvoting the unhelpful answer so it's more clear that the "accepted" answer is no longer working.  I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: @Blackhole I ended up doing your method. In my actual code it was a bit more complex, but it's fundamentally maintaining a new vs. existing array. I'll mark yours as the answer if you move your response to an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @CaptainStack I'll make a clean answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should update your binding of scope variable on blur, for that you should look at [`ng-model-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)

I'd suggest that you should go for `ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"` for the field which is mentioned in orderBy filter

```
<input ng-model="person.lastName" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }>
```

**Note**

> For this you need update angular to 1.3 +

Comment: Drat, we're on 1.2 to get IE8 support. I liked this solution a lot though.